# Executing a command if a program outputs a special string in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have am using a backup script that uses rsync to create a backup of my data, encrypts it and uploads it to the cloud. The script runs in an isolated docker container which only has access to the data it should backup (it cannot *communicate* with the host).

As the services whose data is backed up may not be running while backing up, I am currently executing the backup task (simplified) like this

```
#!/bin/bash
/etc/init.d/myservice stop
# the scripts blocks until the backup job is done
/opt/backup_data >> /var/log/backup.log
/etc/init.d/myservice start
```

and the output of the backup service looks like

```
backup started at 15-02-09 22:00:01
rsync started
/foo/bar
deleted /baz
[...]
rsync completed
starting upload
upload completed
backup completed
```

While this works, I would prefer to restart my services as soon as the rsync operation is finished, to keep the downtime as small as possible. But as all I have is the content of the log, how can I realized this?

TL;DR I run a command that outputs some text to stdout, which I redirect to file. I want to enforce that another command is executed as soon as the stdout of the first one contains a special string. If it doesn't (e.g. while something went wrong), I want to execute it anyway - but only once.

Comment: It's the `/opt/backup_data` script that really needs help here, I think.  Can you include that in your question?  Another option you might consider is staging your backup to a different location on the source host, then restarting services before the rsync even starts.  Then rsync your local backup to the remote host after the service is restarted.

Comment: @ghoti the script starts a Docker container which uses [s3ql](http://www.rath.org/s3ql-docs/index.html) to upload the data encrypted, compressed and chunked to the cloud (`docker start -a svc_backup`). The container just mounts s3ql, runs rsync and unmounts the s3ql  fs (which takes the most time, as it uploads all data before unmounting).

Comment: Either pipe the output of the command through `awk` directly, or run `tail -f` on the logfile and then pipe that into `awk`. Write your `awk` script like this `awk '/rsync done/{system("...something...")}'`

Comment: @MarkSetchell great thanks, but why tail -f?

Comment: `tail -f` will *follow* the log file as it grows....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the docker container's host can *see* the log file, I would use `tail -f` to "*follow*" the log file and pipe its output into `awk`. When `awk` "*sees*" that the `rsync` job is complete, it can restart the services:

```
tail -f backup.log | awk '/^rsync complete/ {system("/etc/init.d/myservice start")}'
```